# Should I trust AutoFull.com?

Tags: websites, safe-browsing-filter

I want to buy a chair from this website http://www.autofull.com/ but the entire website says it is "not secure" except when I press the "settlement/pay now" button and it takes me to a new website that is "secure" https://secure.oceanpayment.com/

I've searched EVERYWHERE to see if this company is legit or not. Most of the time I just find their Amazon. Sadly the thing I want to buy is out of stock on Amazon :/

If anyone has ordered from there your help will be greatly appreciated. I do a lot of searching before I order from an unfamiliar website and this one has me stumped!

Comment: Unfortunately, we cannot do site reviews for safety. And we cannot investigate companies for you. As for whether the "not secure" thing is a problem, the duplicate covers that.

Answer (score 0):

Not Secure means not secure. If they can't get HTTPS on their site or HTTPS to work well, I wouldn't trust their website.

You do have options:

- Call them and place the order over the phone.
- Just heard about this: https://privacy.com/ - they give you a one time use, a changing credit card number, or something similar

This is really about you protecting yourself from credit card theft.

And if you're worried about credit card theft, know that your bank actually will cover you. It's a hassle, but you aren't liable for stolen credit information (in America).

So, rather than spending time to understand "not secure," assume the website is not secure, and decide how to mitigate your risk.

Answer (score 0):

That's not *that* unusual for really small e-commerce sites. There are tons of hassles with using small e-commerce sites including people not noticing that you've placed an order, inadequately fixed or mitigated hacking attacks, a lack of system administration attenion, and a lack of an aggregator like Ebay/Amazon/Etsy to complain to if they're being unprofessional. On the brighter side you'd be supporting your indie e-commerce industry.

It sounds like the actual money goes to and through a third party, which is good. You may also want to email them to see if they sell the product via an aggregator like Ebay/Amazon/Etc. Even if they don't it's a good way of checking whether they'll notice your order.